# PHP fails when upgraded to 5.4

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP with MySQL to pull programs, courses, etc. on 2003 box with PHP 5.2. I am transferring my site to a new 2008 box with PHP 5.4 (because of injection exploits on database). My data still pulls to my site (programs, courses etc) from my new server.

The issue is I have a page that is for login and will not load (HTTP 500 error). I have traced back to section of code that kicks out and believe it is the `session_start()`. I know in 5.3 it changed and will now return false if it fails to start instead of the previous true.

I've tried echoing out what loads line by line with each variable since I can compare it with the two versions. I've tried starting the session at the beginning. Ending it before my code, etc. It seems simple, but I haven't got it to work yet.

Here's the beginning of my page "login-inc-header.php":

```
<?php
    if(!isset($session_started)) $session_started = session_start();
    // avoids duplicate pstings
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
    ini_set("display_errors", "1");
    if(!isset($requires)) $requires = "User";
    include_once("includes/handleLogin.php"); 
    include_once("../includes_app/db_settings.php");
?>
```

If I remove this block, The page will load just without my login boxes. Pages works perfect in version 5.2. Ideas?

My db_settings:

```
<?php
    //$site_root = "/var/www/html/";
    $site_root = "C:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\";  //changed 12-13-13 for new server
    //$site_root = substr($_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED'], 0, (-1 * strlen($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])));
    $site_url = "http://10.20.251.60/";

    include_once($site_root."includes_app/adodb/adodb.inc.php");
    $db =& ADONewConnection('mysql');
    $db->Connect("localhost", "####", "####", "####");

    $db->SetFetchMode(ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC);

    // for mysql only...make sure we are NOT in strict mode
    $db->Execute("SET sql_mode=''");

    $tblprefix = "";
    $extraFieldLabHours = true; 
    $extraFieldOBIHours = true; 
    $extraFieldsPrereqCoreq = true;
    $extraFieldProgramRequirements = true;
    $maxCourseCodeLength = 4;
    $maxCoursePrefixLength = 4; // 11-05-10 added this line to fix prefix length
    $exportReport[$site_url.'includes_app/html_word_export.php'] = "Export for Microsoft Word 2007";
    $exportReport[$site_url.'includes_app/html_rtf_export.php'] = "Export for Adobe InDesign CS2";
    $exportReport[$site_url.'directory/print.php'] = "Export Directory to HTML";
    $sysadmin_email = "gntc@gntc.edu";
    $extraModuleEmployeeDirectory = true;
    $extraModuleCampusAlert = true;
    $extraFieldAtAGlance = true;
    $areas = array();
    $configAreasResult = $db->Execute("SELECT dbName, displayName FROM ".$tblprefix."areas ORDER BY sequence");
    while($configRow = $configAreasResult->fetchRow()) $areas[$configRow['dbName']] = $configRow['displayName'];
    $program_types = array();
    $configProgramTypesResult = $db->Execute("SELECT dbName, displayName FROM ".$tblprefix."program_types ORDER BY sequence");
    while($configRow = $configProgramTypesResult->fetchRow()) $program_types[$configRow['dbName']] = $configRow['displayName'];
    $extraFieldCampus = array();
    $configCampusesResult = $db->Execute("SELECT displayName FROM ".$tblprefix."campuses ORDER BY sequence");
    while($configRow = $configCampusesResult->fetchRow()) $extraFieldCampus[] = $configRow['displayName'];
    $extraFieldEmployeeOfficeHours = true;
    $extraFieldEmployeeBio = true;
    $extraFieldEmployeePicture = true;
    $extraFieldFoptNumRequirements = true;
    $alternateTitleGeneralCoreCourses = "General Core Curriculum";
    $alternateTitleOccupationalCourses = "Occupational Curriculum";
    $extraModuleCampusAlert = true; // added on 3-10-10 to make campus alert feature work
    $alternateTitleEmployeeEducation = "Credentials"; $showBannerID = true;  
    $deeperMenus = true; 
    $importModules = array(); 
    $importModules['import_courses_xml.php'] = "Courses XML"; 
    $importModules['import_employees_xml.php'] = "Employees XML"; 
    $extraModuleDivisions = true; 
    $gntc_local_upload_dir = $site_root."uploads/"; 
    $gntc_web_upload_dir = $site_url."uploads/"; 
    $exportReport[$site_url.'includes_app/phone_sheet_csv.php'] = "Phone Sheet CSV";
?>
```

Log File:

> [16-Jan-2014 21:17:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(includes/handleLogin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\login\includes\header.php on line 8
>
> [16-Jan-2014 21:17:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'includes/handleLogin.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\login\includes\header.php on line 8
>
> [16-Jan-2014 21:17:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(../includes_app/db_settings.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\login\includes\header.php on line 9
>
> [16-Jan-2014 21:17:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '../includes_app/db_settings.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\login\includes\header.php on line 9
>
> [16-Jan-2014 21:17:46 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: title in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\login\includes\header.php on line 16
>
> [16-Jan-2014 21:17:46 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: title in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\login\includes\header.php on line 159

I noticed that this referenced PEAR, which in not installed by default like older versions. Could this be the issue?

Comment: So then your includes contain files with some things which are deprecated in new versions (like pass-by-reference)

Comment: You should check the error that is written to the logfile and show use the error that is displayed there, because there you will see the exact reason. If you run php as apache module then look into the apache error log file.

Comment: As long as you don't post your error message it is very unlikely that you will get an answer. We all volunteers here, spending our spar time, so we don't dig line for line through your code to find your error especially if the error message with the actual line where this happens can be provided by you. So if you want help then invest the time to show the error message.

Comment: I'm working on getting the file.

Comment: @t.niese what I don't get is he is displaying the errors on the page through `ini_set("display_errors", "1");` in the `login-inc-header.php` yet still getting a 500 instead of seeing the errors on the page.

Comment: Just added display errors to see them.

Comment: If "includes\header.php" is including "includes\handleLogin.php", I wonder whether it is ending up with the pathname "includes\includes\handleLogin.php". Thus, if it just includes "handleLogin.php" instead, it will find the file in the same directory.

Comment: Read the Changelogs for PHP 5.4 and see what has changed between 5.2 and 5.4.

Comment: Copied over PEAR folder to new PHP. Also, changed open_basedir in php.ini file to include c:\windows\TEMP. This fixed the issue! Thank you all SO MUCH for all of your help!!

Comment: Are you on Windows 2008 or 2008 r2 (32bit or 64bit)?  Also which version of PHP are you using a 32bit or 64bit?

Answer (score 0):

You have put this as your site root

```
$site_root = "C:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\";
```

Try putting

```
$site_root = "http://yourhost/folder_name/"
```